# Directory in Downloads from Mathematica Install

Tags: linux

I installed Mathematica on Linux (PopOs) and it runs perfectly, I was going through my harddrive and found a folder within Downloads, which is called Downloads/.19882 it is 4.5 Gb. Within it there's another one called Unix. Within there are a bunch of files that Mathematica seemed to have placed there. I wonder if it is safe to remove? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you name one or two of the files? What makes you think Mathematica put them there? I also recently installed Mathematica on Pop!_Os  and I don't have this folder, anyway :)

Comment: Hello, yes. Within .19882/Unix/Installer/MathInstaller and it looks like this:

#!/bin/bash
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#   Installer for Mathematica Applications
#
#   This file and all scripts and messages accessed from this file
#        (c) 2004 Wolfram Research, Inc. All rights reserved.
#
#

LANG=C
export LANG 

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Function: BuildDesktopFile()

Comment: Well, that certainly looks like the installer for Mathematica, which is about that size. It can probably be deleted. I would suggest moving it and seeing if Mathematica opens and runs fine with that file in a different place, and if so, just removing it.

Comment: Simple rename it and see if mathematica is running.

Comment: Renaming and launching mathematica worked like a charm so I can assume it is safe to delete. Thanks everyone!